# iCloud photo library - Lost locations

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos, geolocation

I must mention that I've contacted Apple support many many times about that, there were a bunch of call back from them and email conversations with senior advisors, but there was no success in finding a solution for this issue.

What they've told me in our final conversation over the phone was: "The engineers are working on this issue and we have couple of reports with the same issue as you do so you must wait till they find a solution".

The reason I'm opening this discussion is to see if there is somebody else with the same issue as mine or anybody has successfully resolved it.

Now let begin with the explanation of the issue.

I can see no locations in YEARS, while in COLLECTION and MOMENTS there are locations visible. We are talking only for year 2015. And yes LOCATION was turned ON while using Camera in Settings.

[image]

As you can see there are no locations for 2015 while for 2014 and 2016 there are.
Lets take a look into Collections and Moments:

[image]

MOMENTS:

[image]

So now there are locations, and also if I select a picture from the same year there will be a location.

[image]

I was unable to resolve this issue even after changing my device, from iPhone 5s to iPhone 7 Plus.
I would really appreciate if you give me any tips for how to resolve this, if anybody already done that.(?)

***Note: I've posted the same question a long time ago on a couple of other forums but still no answer. Only on one of the forums I got a question if an advisor from apple asked me to restore the device. The answer is Yes. I made a backup of my iPhone 5s and restored it from the backup and still nothing. I even tried setting it up as a "new iPhone".
I tried this even with my iPhone 7 Plus.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one has to do with your iCloud account. 
First of all you need to be up to date to all of your Apple devices under the same appleid (your appleid). Then my suggestion is to log out of your iCloud account to all of your devices and login back again. Also check Photos location services (that’s under settings/ privacy / location services/ photos) should be “ WHILE USING”.  Reboot your devices and see how it goes. Cheers.

Comment: `And yes LOCATION was turned ON while using Camera in Settings.` Which means that Photo location was ON `while using` for Camera. Please see my original post. Also, the same thing I was trying to do with the Apple Advisors and it didn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Then.   General/reset/reset location & privacy 
I see no other reason an iPhone to not geotagging photos.

Comment: IT IS gathering, just not showing them in the YEAR tab.